# MvvmLight SimpleIoc and multiple concrete implementations

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, ioc-container

With `SimpleIoc` I'd like to register multiple implementations of `IProvider`, something like:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IProvider, Provider1>();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IProvider, Provider2>();
```

So I can do:

```
var providers = SimpleIoc.GetAllInstances<IProvider>();
```

Is there a way to do something like this?  If I try it as is I get that there is already a class registered for `IProvider`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by implementing a base class and using keyed registrations:

```
public interface IProvider { }
public abstract class BaseProvider : IProvider { }
public class Provider1 : BaseProvider { }
public class Provider2 : BaseProvider { }

[Test]
public void RegisterTwoImplementations_GetAllInstances_ReturnsBothInstances()
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Provider1>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Provider2>();

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<BaseProvider>(() => 
            SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<Provider1>(), "a" );

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<BaseProvider>(() =>
            SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<Provider2>(), "b");

    var result = SimpleIoc.Default.GetAllInstances<BaseProvider>();

    Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(result.Count(), Is.EqualTo(2));
    Assert.That(result.Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Provider1)), Is.True);
    Assert.That(result.Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Provider2)), Is.True);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I was close.  I registered `IProvider1` and `IProvider2` and each inherited from `IProvider`.  Then I registered `IEnumerable<IProvider>` and the factory returned the collection.  I like your way better.  Thanks!