# IoC container in MVVMLight - How to pass concrete implementation to the specified element?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mvvm-light, ioc-container

I'm currently struggling with following problem with an IoC container from Mvvm Light - I have an interface `IDataService`, which is being implemented by two classes: `DataService1` and `DataService2`. I also have `MainViewModel` class that has many dependencies, with one being  `IDataService`.

The point is, I want to supply `MainViewModel` with `DataService2`, not the other one. How can I do that? I've tried to "key" both instances of the `IDataService` and the `MainViewModel`, like that:

```
class MainViewModel 
{
    // MainViewModel has many dependencies, 
    public MainViewModel(X x, Y y, Z z, M m, N n, IDataService dataService) { }
}

(...)

SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService>(() => new DataService1(), "A");
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService>(() => new DataService2(), "B");


(...)

var viewModel = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainViewModel>("B"); // Runtime exception
```

but I get runtime exception which basically says that the `MainViewModel` cannot be resolved - from what I've understood if I want to resolve **keyed** `MainViewModel` ("B"), all of its dependencies have to be keyed. This is not what I want - I want to resolve `MainViewModel` that has default dependencies, except for the one.

How can I do that? I'm clearly missing something. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the exact exception message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301891/mvvmlight-simpleioc-and-multiple-concrete-implementations

Comment: @RomanKo I'm getting ActivationException.

Additional information: Type not found in cache without a key: ViewModels.MainViewModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate to say, but it looks like the only way. You have to register a keyed factory:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>(() => new MainViewModel(new X(), new Y(), new Z(), new M(), new N(), SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IDataService>("B")), "B");
```

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion. But it practically defeats the purpose of using IoC-Container -because classes X, Y, Z have their own dependencies, which now I have to provide. 

Thank you though for your input! I'll wait a little bit more, and if noone answers, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Malutek: Yep. Hence the name: **Simple** Ioc.

Comment: @romanoza Do you know any Ioc which could do it more elegant way?