# MVVM Light SimpleIoc instance resolution

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, mvvm-light

In my MVVM Light I display a dialog by having it implement an IModalWindow interface. I could register it using

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IModalWindow, DialogView>();
```

Using this method though I cannot see how I can register different dialogs that implement the same interface and request the correct one. I looked at the factory method but could not find a suitable example.

Instead I used the following

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IModalWindow>(() => { return new DialogView(); }, "DialogView");
```

which allows me to access a specific dialog type via the key, but since this is a singleton, I get an error when I attempt to show the dialog a second time because the instance has been closed.

This second method also allows a Mock to be used for unit testing by registering it with the same key.

How can I register different dialogs with SimpleIoc, get non-singleton instances and be able to unit test?

Comment: I do not know if MEF can handle such a situation but to solve my problem, I created a `ModalWindowFactory` (implementing `IModalWindowFactory` interface) with a create method to fetch correct classes from SimpleIoc. I registered the factory class with SimpleIoc. For unit testing I just create a Mock factory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301891/mvvmlight-simpleioc-and-multiple-concrete-implementations has the needed details :)

Comment: @Depechie - I had already looked at that solution but it does not work for me because it still represents a singleton and I will get an error the second time I try to open the dialog as I mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Maybe you didn't look long at the given link? it's stated in the solution how to enable resolving an instance without it being a singleton! But I'll repeat it here: SimpleIoc.Default.Register<BaseProvider>(() =>             SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<Provider1>(), "a" ); So when you provide a KEY for an instance it's each time a different version! This works too SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()); However the instances will be cached, so if you do not want to keep them in the cache, you will need to call Unregister with the corresponding key.

Comment: I understood the link just fine. Using the key provides a way get different Provider instances (or different dialog views). The key helps resolve to the correct type. However, it is effectively a singleton for that key (because it is cached) and is fine for viewmodel classes. When dealing with dialog windows, it does not work. After the dialog is closed, you cannot re-acquire it with the same key and show it again because it is closed. I would need to unregister and re-register outside of the ViewModelLocator which I do not want to do - hence I am using a factory to create my dialog instances.